# The Madman's Speech

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

You are walking through the prairie when you find a madman wandering around talking to himself. The following is what you manage to hear of his speech:

> "How? I - I'll ask her. I owe her much, again. I'd a home on town, a tax as florid as out the coat, a virgin a year. Oh, yodel - aware you take all or I do. Never the road: I'll land in the Anna-Marie land. Main can's a sore gone; tennis is out t'car. Oh, line a canned turkey!"

**What is the man really talking about?**

Comment: Plot twist - You are the only one in the prairie. You, are the madman!

Comment: Anna-Marie land and yodel - aware kinda gave it away.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I guess he's talking about

> States in America.
>
>  "How? - I" = Hawaii
>  "I'll ask her." = Alaska
>  "I owe her" = Iowa
>  "much again" = Michigan
>  "I'd a ho..." = Idaho
>  "...me on town, a" = Montana
>  "tax as" = Texas
>  "florid a..." = Florida
>  "...s out the coat, a" = South Dakota
>  "virgin a year." = Virginia
>  "Oh yo..." = Ohio
>  "...del - aware" = Delaware
>  "You ta..." = Utah
>  "...ke all or i do" = Colorado
>  "Never the" = Nevada
>  "road: I'll land" = Rhode Island
>  "in the Anna-..." = Indiana
>  "...Marie land" = Maryland
>  "Main" = Maine
>  "can's a s..." = Kansas
>  "...ore gone;" = Oregon
>  "tennis i..." = Tennessee
>  "...s out t'car. Oh line a" = South Carolina
>  "canned Turkey" = Kentucky

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's explained better (although posted later) than Prem's. Nice one!

Comment: I think that was a wise choice taken by @randal'thor , after checking with me. Now , I feel that while I got the "harder" populist badge, the extra points for accepted answer will be "more useful" for QBrute.

Answer (score 67):

Short :

> He is talking about the states in the United States.

Details:

> "Hawaii Alaska Iowa Michigan Idaho Montana Texas Florida SouthDakota Virginia Ohio Delaware Utah Colorado Nevada RhodeIsland Indiana Maryland Maine Kansas Oregon Tennessee SouthCarolina Kentucky"