# Met an odd pirate, where was he?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

Ran into a pirate at a bar, the old fashioned kind. I asked him where he'd been and he gave me a cryptic response.

> Sail on, found in
>
> utter majesteer', I
>
> mean, on 'me,
>
> paluk paneer
>
> speaking s'pecifically
>
> lower countries sped though
>
> high seas

A couple of hints.

> The pirate speaks a certain east asian language. That said, he was not in east asia.

Comment: Re: Hint - does that mean you need to know another language?

Comment: Also are we working out where he's _been_, or where he is _now_?

Comment: Where he's been, but the riddle was not designed with tense in mind. And yeah, but look at the way the lines are structured for the foreign language clue - it's more of a question of matching sounds to the spellings.

Comment: So when are we gonna get the solution? I'm losing sleep over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

> Sri Lanka

Sail on, found in

> Found in Ceylon - Ceylon (or British Ceylon) was the name for Sri Lanka from 1815 to 1948

I can't work out any other lines, although:

paluk paneer

> Paneer is Indian Cheese. How that references Sri Lanka other than being a neighbouring country I don't know

lower countries sped though

> It's the lowest country in West Asia?

Comment: I'll accept this since it's been awhile and this puzzle wasn't well worded. You were right on the paneer, it is a neighboring country- "mean on me" => "mi na n me" => "mi na mi" => みなみ aka south. It's south of india. Low countries is the netherlands, which had had a presence there. But so had they in a lot of places.

Answer (score 1):

Given the [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay) tag, as well as some of the words chosen, I think the puzzle is based on the same idea as [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16513/the-madmans-speech).

Specifically:

> "Sail on" -> **Ceylon**, "speaking s'pecifically" -> [s]**Peking** [s]**Pacific** [...]

I haven't solved it all yet, but this looks like the right 'aha' needed.

Comment: Keep on, keep on...

Comment: Well, close. I actually hadn't realized the Peking part, oops. But that's the wrong direction... I'll add some hints!

Comment: In case that wasn't clear, those are the right aha's more or less.

Comment: @JamieBarker I'll say that if you post an answer and flesh out the clues you got it.

Answer (score 1):

Sail on, Found in

> Ceylon (name for Sri Lanka), Poondi, Tamil Nadu or Fonadhoo, Maldives or "foun" day/s

utter majesteer', I

> There I was served tea. or I was attacked by arrow (Andaman Islands are home to the only known paleolithic people; still use bow and arrow.)

mean, on 'me, paluk paneer

> On the menu, paluk paneer (India-Subcontinental Cottage cheese dish)

speaking s'pecifically

> Speaking *Pacific*-ly

lower countries

> Lower could mean like Netherlands, or South

sped though high seas

> It has two high seas (around it).

I can't be sure of anything. It should help other though.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> The Netherlands

I couldn't make much of it except for one part which makes me think this:

> Netherlands literally means "Low countries" matching the "lower countries" part in the riddle

Comment: Can you explain how this fits any of the rest of the riddle besides those two words (which could also refer to East Anglia, parts of the Middle East, or any other low-lying territory)?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Mark, explain to me why this isn't an answer to the question. The question asks for a location and I provide one. I even use one of the clues for it. It's true that I don't use all clues but I also indicated that I couldn't make much out of it. So yes this is a bit of a wild guess but is that really not allowed? Should I really be 100% certain that I'm right? I think not. I think everyone is allowed to guess the answer and that is what also makes this site fun. Feel free to downvote if you like because that is also allowed.

Comment: @IvoBeckers, I believe this answer would be more appropriate as a comment until it provides a more complete solution or address the entire puzzle. This is to prevent an excess of answers being posted that only address a specific part of the puzzle. You are welcome to have a partial solution that is a Work In Progress, but I would suggest labeling it as such if you do so (until the entire puzzle is addressed in some way for your solution).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the pirate has been to

> Andaman and Nicobar Islands

Sail On Found In

> It is in the middle of the ocean having no borders with another country.

paluk paneer

> Which happens to be an Indian dish

lower countries sped though

> It is on the lower side of the Indian mainland.

high seas

*Unsure about this clue...*

Comment: Heading in the right direction as well.