# Fill in the blank word:

Tags: word, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Fill in the blank word: (myriad, Alito, lame, moose, fleas, wash, wide, ass, know, endeavor, worth, it, _____, wind, dilemmas, shirt, ago)

Comment: Hi Dielst, welcome to PSE! Please take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour). Where did this question come from? Having the source written in the question if it was not original helps us spot plagiarism. Thank you. - From Review

Comment: The original author of it, who may be me, gives permission for people to retell it.  When someone figures out the trick to it they will be fairly certain they got it.

Comment: Your prior comment unfortunately allows others to infer that you are not the original author. As such, I'm voting to close this on the basis that proper attribution is required. If it's your puzzle, you can leave a comment here explicitly stating that it is of your own creation, and then vote to reopen.

Comment: It is my original creation.

Comment: Yes i thought it up all by myself, so how do i vote to re-open? I  hereby vote to re-open it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the missing word is

> merry

Reasoning

> If you read the words in order it sounds like the first couple of lines from the nursery rhyme [Mary Had a Little Lamb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Had_a_Little_Lamb), that is
>  "Mary had a little lamb whose fleece was white as snow, and everywhere that Mary went, the lamb was sure to go"
>  sounds like
>  myriad, Alito, lame, moose, fleas, wash, wide, ass, know, endeavor, worth, it, **merry**, wind, dilemmas, shirt, ago

Comment: [Related](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16513/5373) (spoilerously).

Comment: Yes. hexomino got it!